# How can I fix these overlapping HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, element

Can someone take a look at my code please and tell me:

1. How can I get the image to go over the `<header>` and `<nav>` so that everything else centres properly. I have tried playing with z-index and nothing seems to work.
2. How do I get the `<section>` to start under the `<nav>` rather than right at the top of the page behind the other elements without using loads of `<br>`s?

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

body {
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif
}

header {
 background-color: #ffd800;
 color: black;
 height: 119px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: -20px -10px;
 min-width: 800px;
 position: fixed;
 margin: -20px -10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.logo {
 float:left;
 width: 118px;
 height: 118px;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

header h2 {
 min-width: 800px;
}

nav ul {
 background-color: #ffd800;
 text-align:center;
 list-style: none;
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

nav li {
 display: inline;
}

nav a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 30px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
 color: white;
}

section {
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 background-color: #ffff80;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
 padding: 0 40px 5px 40px
}

section h3 {
 text-align: center;
}

.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Chris Atkinson</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 
 <header>
  <img class="logo" src="resources/img/chris.gif" alt="logo">
  <br>
  <h2>Web Design by Chris Atkinson</h2>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <section>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h3>Welcome to my site</h3>
  <p>Please take a good look around, and send me some feedback in
   the 'contact' section. I'd love to hear from you</p>
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these css properties and you should be able to get rid of all the breaks:

```
section {
   width: 800px;
   background-color: #ffff80;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
   padding: 100px 40px 5px 40px
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

No need to float left on the logo if you are doing an absolute position. Also, you you want to add top padding (the first value in the padding property) of your section to shift it down below the nav.

http://jsbin.com/woyilesoka/2/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your logo away from your other stuff.  Make your logo position: absolute; and create a z-index greater than the divs below it.  This way it's above your other divs, and not included in the divs.  This will keep the rest of your stuff centered.

Directions:

```
.logo {
position: absolute;
z-index : 9000;
float:left;
width: 118px;
height: 118px;
}
```

then move the logo left.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make your logo position absolute so that the float of other elements do not interfere with your logo:

   ```
   .logo {
   position: absolute;
   width: 118px;
   height: 118px;
   margin-right: 50px;
   }
   ```
2. This is how your make your section below the nav bar by changing margin on the top of the section:

   ```
   section {
   margin: 2opx auto 0 auto;
   width: 800px;
   background-color: #ffff80;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
   padding: 0 40px 5px 40px;
   }
   ```